# How to perform a count on a arbitrary query (possibly containing a order by)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, .net-4.0

I have been tasked with updating our internal framework we use in-house. One of the things the framework does is you pass it a query and it will return the number of rows the query has in it (The framework makes heavy use of DataReaders so we need the total before hand for UI things).

The query that the count needs to be done on can be different from project to project (SOL-injection is not a issue, the query is not from user input, just hard coded in from another programmer when they use the framework for their project.) and I was told that just having the programmers write a second query for the count is unacceptable.

Currently the solution is to do the following (I did not write this, I was just told to fix it).

```
//executes query and returns record count
public static int RecordCount(string SqlQuery, string ConnectionString, bool SuppressError = false)
{

    //SplitLeft is just myString.Substring(0, myString.IndexOf(pattern)) with some error checking. and InStr is just a wrapper for IndexOf.
    //remove order by clause (breaks count(*))
    if (Str.InStr(0, SqlQuery.ToLower(), " order by ") > -1)
        SqlQuery = Str.SplitLeft(SqlQuery.ToLower(), " order by ");

    try
    {
        //execute query
        using (SqlConnection cnSqlConnect = OpenConnection(ConnectionString, SuppressError))
        using (SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from (" + SqlQuery + ") as a", cnSqlConnect))
        {
            SqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 120;
            return (Int32)SqlCmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (SuppressError == false)
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Sql.RecordCount()");

        return -1;
    }

}
```

However it breaks on queries like (again, not my query, I just need to make it work)

```
select [ClientID], [Date], [Balance] 
from [Ledger] 
where Seq = (select top 1 Seq 
             from [Ledger] as l 
             where l.[ClientID] = [Ledger].[ClientID] 
             order by [Date] desc, Seq desc) 
      and Balance <> 0)
```

as it will removes everything after the `order by` and breaks the query. I thought I may go from simple string matching to a more complicated parser, but before I do that I wanted to ask if there is a better way.

**UPDATE:** The order by clause is dropped because if you include it using my method or a CTE you will get the error `The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.`

**Some more details:** This framework is used for writing conversion applications. We write apps to pull data from a clients old database and move it in to our database format when a customer buys our [CRM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customer_relationship_management) software. Often we are working with source tables that are poorly written and can be several Gigs in size. We do not have the resources to hold the whole table in memory so we use a DataReader to pull the data out so everything is not in memory at once. However a requirement is a progress bar with the total number of records to be processed. This RecordCount function is used to figure the max of the progress bar. It works fairly well, the only snag is if the programmer writing the conversion needs to order the data output, having a `order by` clause in the outer most query breaks `count(*)`

---

**Partial Solution:** I came up with this while trying to figure it out, it will not work 100% of the time but I think it will be better than the current solution

If I find a order by clause, I then check to see if the first thing in the query is a select (and no Top following) I replace that beginning text with `select top 100 percent`. It works better but I am not posting this as a solution as I am hoping for a universal solution.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do.  You want a query so that you can use a progress bar, what are you counting exactly?

Comment: @KevinHolditch The number of rows that would be returned from the unmodified query. That will be used for the max value of the progress bar. I will update the post for clarity.

Comment: One way would be to use LINQ and `IQueryable<T>` instead of SQL strings. Except that would require a rewrite of all your applications, so it's probably not a short-term solution.

Comment: @svick I really wish I could, but one of the commands from on high is "It must not break backwards compatibility with already written programs"

Comment: @sivick would you post a answer of how to do this "the right way" using IQueryable, if I can understand how to do that better maybe I can convince the person above me to make the old interface depreceated and make a new interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you aren't going to see anything but fairly ordinary `select` statements, I don't think you don't need a full-on SQL parser to do what you want. You can reasonably make the assumption that you've got syntactically valid SQL. You need to build a tokenizer (lexical analyzer), though.

The lexical analysis needed for Transact SQL is pretty simple. The token list consist of (off the top of my head, since it's been a while since I had to do this):

- whitespace
- two types of comments:

  - `--`-style comments
    /*...*/`-style comments
- three types of quoted literals:

  - string literals (e.g., `'my string literal'), and
  - two flavors of quoting reserved words for use as column or object names:

    - ANSI/ISO style, using double quotes (e.g., `"table"`)
    - Transact-SQL style, using square-brackets (e.g., `[table]`)
- hex literals (e.g., `0x01A2F`)
- numeric literals (e.g. `757`, `-3218`, `5.4` or `-7.6E-32`, `5.0m` , `$5.3201` etc.)
- words, reserved or not: a unicode letter, underscore ('*'), 'at'-sign ('@') or hash ('#'), followed by zero or more of unicode letters, decimal digits, underscore ('*') or the at-, dollar- or hash- signs ('@', '$' or '#').
- operators, including parentheses.

It can pretty much all be done with regular expressions. If you were using [Perl](http://www.perl.org/), you'd be done in a day, easy. It'll probably take a bit longer in C#, though.

I would probably treat comments as whitespace and collapse multiple sequences of whitespace and comment into a single whitespace token as it facilitates the recognition of constructs such as `order by`.

The reason you don't need a parser is that you don't really care very much about the parse tree. What you do care about is nested parentheses. So...

1. Once you've gotten a lexical analyzer that emits a stream of tokens, all you need to do is eat and discard tokens counting open/closing parentheses until you see a 'from' keyword at parenthetical depth 0.
2. Write `select count(*)` into your StringBuilder.
3. Start appending tokens (including the `from`) into the StringBuilder until you see an 'order by' at parenthetical depth 0. You'll need to build a certain amount of look-ahead into your lexer to do this (which see my earlier note regarding the collapsing of sequences of whitespace and/or comments into a single whitespace token.)
4. At this point, you should be pretty much done. Execute the query.

**NOTES**

1. Parameterized queries likely won't work.
2. Recursive queries, with a CTE and a `with` clause will probably get broken.
3. This will discard anything past the `ORDER BY` clause: if the query uses query hint, a `FOR` clause, or `COMPUTE`/`COMPUTE BY`, your results will likely differ from the original query (especially with any `compute` clauses, since those break up the queries result sets).
4. Bare `UNION` queries will get broken, since something like

   ```
         select c1,c2 from t1
   UNION select c1,c2 from t2
   ```

   will get turned into

   ```
         select count(*) from t1
   UNION select c1,c2 from t2
   ```
5. All this is completely untested, just my thoughts based on oddball stuff I've had to do over the years.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of modifying the existing clauses of the query - how about inserting a new clause, the INTO clause.

```
SELECT *
INTO #MyCountTable -- new clause to create a temp table with these records.
FROM TheTable

SELECT @@RowCount
-- or maybe this:
--SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #MyCountTable

DROP TABLE #MyCountTable
```

TSql query modification seems to be an eternal struggle to be the lastest thing that happens.

Answer (score 1):

> would you post a answer of how to do this "the right way" using IQueryable

Suppose you had some arbitrary query:

```
IQueryable<Ledger> query = myDataContext.Ledgers
  .Where(ledger => ledger.Seq ==
    myDataContext.Ledgers
      .Where(ledger2 => ledger2.ClientId == ledger.ClientId)
      .OrderByDescending(ledger2 => ledger2.Date)
      .ThenByDescending(ledger2 => ledger2.Seq)
      .Take(1).SingleOrDefault().Seq
  )
  .Where(ledger => ledger.Balance != 0);
```

Then you just get the Count of the rows, no need for any custom method or query manipulation.

```
int theCount = query.Count();

//demystifying the extension method:
//int theCount = System.Linq.Queryable.Count(query);
```

LinqToSql will include your desire for a count into the query text.

Answer (score 0):

What if rather than try to re-build your query, you do something like:

```
WITH MyQuery AS (
select [ClientID], [Date], [Balance] 
from [Ledger] 
where Seq = (select top 1 Seq 
            from [Ledger] as l 
                where l.[ClientID] = [Ledger].[ClientID] 
            order by [Date] desc, Seq desc) 
      and Balance <> 0)
)
  SELECT COUNT(*) From MyQuery;
```

Note I haven't tested this on SQL Server 2005 but it should work.

**Update:**

We've confirmed SQL Server 2005 does not support an ORDER BY clause within a CTE.  This does, however, work with Oracle and perhaps other databases.

Comment: That won't work when it's a simple "select x from table order by x" since order by isn't allowed in a CTE

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. it is throws the same error as my current method. `The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.`

Comment: Doh!  Yea, I just tried it in Oracle and it lets you have ORDER BY in a CTE.  So I figured it was worth a shot.  I'll leave my answer up in case it helps someone at some point though.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to drop the order by clause to improve the performance. The general case is quite complex and you will need full sql parser to drop the ordering clause.

Also, did you check the comparative performance of

```
select count(id) from ....
```

v/s

```
select count(*) from (select id, a+b from ....)
```

The problem is that the a+b will need to be evaluated in latter, essentially executing query twice.

If you want a progress bar because the retrieval itself is slow then this is completely counter-productive, because you will spend almost the same amount of time estimating the count.

And if the application is complex enough that the data can change between the two query execution then you don't even know how reliable the count is.

So: the real answer is that you cannot get a count on arbitrary query in efficient way. For a non-efficient way, if your resultset is rewindable, then go the end of resultset, figure out the row count and then go back to the first row.

Comment: It is not a performance issue, see the update in the OP. You can not use order by in a count(*) query.

Comment: It still requires full parsing of the original query.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't edit or try to parse the SQL at all, but you may have to use an [EVIL CURSOR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58141/why-is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-use-cursors-in-sql-server) (don't worry, we won't explicitly iterate through anything).  Here, I would simply pass your ad-hoc SQL to a proc which runs it as a cursor, and returns the number of rows in the cursor.  There may be some optimizations available, but I've kept it simple, and this should work for **any** valid select statement (even CTEs) that you pass to it. No need to code and debug your own T-SQL lexer or anything.

```
create proc GetCountFromSelect (
    @SQL nvarchar(max)
)
as
begin
    set nocount on
    exec ('declare CountCursor insensitive cursor for ' + @SQL + ' for read only')
    open CountCursor
    select @@cursor_rows as RecordCount
    close CountCursor
    deallocate CountCursor
end
go

exec GetCountFromSelect '// Your SQL here'
go
```