# Fetching from the Results of Table Functions

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

I use a function and **pipeline** its return values.
I call the above function as:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(FUNC(params)) ORDER BY somecolumn;
```

It returns the results as a **1 x 4** table, and I tried using **cursors** to retrieve them. But is shows an error, saying that a cursor is only for fieldnames or column names and not for **type**.

Is it still possible to use cursors for the same, or is there any other way to retrieve the individual fields.

Comment: Just a note...you should (almost) never use a cursor

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58141/why-is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-use-cursors-in-sql-server for your answer on why to not use a cursor. I am not sure about oracle, so am not sure, but it might help to clarify that your func is a table function (my assumption?)

Comment: @JustinPihony It is indeed one.

Comment: OK, what is your question here, actually? What exactly are you trying to do...that is not really clear to me at least...maybe some sample output or further explanation would help

Comment: @JustinPihony: I am using a function, which I use as: SELECT * FROM TABLE(FUNC(params)) ORDER BY somecolumn; (directly). Now, I need to execute it via pl sql and then retrive each of its fields, i.e. the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want?

```
SELECT MyTable.Column1, MyTable.Column3, etc
FROM TABLE(FUNC(params)) MyTable
ORDER BY somecolumn;
```

To access specific columns, just alias the table.

Comment: I used in pl sql using a cursor: SELECT MyTable.Column1, MyTable.Column3
FROM TABLE(FUNC(params)) MyTable
ORDER BY somecolumn;

It says MyTable.Column1 must be declared.