# What are cursor-less development patterns

Tags: database, rdbms

Recently I came across development patterns call **cursor-less**. I try to find sources and articles about it and I couldn't find any. Can someone provide a example for **cursor-less development patterns** or point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term *cursor-less* is most likely related to databases. Relational database management systems typically provide *cursors* which can be used to iterate over a data set. Some systems also provide other mechanisms like *while loops* for the same purpose.

So *cursor-less development pattern* most probably means nothing more than using loops instead of cursors in database applications. This has nothing to do with general software design patterns.

Here are a few links:

[Comparing cursor vs. WHILE loop performance in SQL Server 2008](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/comparing-cursor-vs-while-loop-performance-in-sql-server-2008/)

[Why is it considered bad practice to use cursors in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58141/why-is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-use-cursors-in-sql-server)

Comment: Thanks for answering the question, it will be great if you can provide a article that i can read more about this.

Comment: @thusharaK: Have added a few links.