# SQL Cursor returns 0 rows when run in same session

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-cursor

I have a stored procedure in which I use a cursor to parse arrays separated by semi-colons (eg `Marketing;Diligence;Deal Flow`) is returned in three separate rows with each value in its own row. The procedure/cursor works perfectly when run in a fresh session. However if I re-run the procedure within the same session, the cursor returns 0 rows.

```
DECLARE @category NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE cursor_product CURSOR LOCAL STATIC FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY FOR 
     SELECT DISTINCT category AS val 
     FROM #temp;

OPEN cursor_product;

CREATE TABLE #temp5
(
     Name varchar(max)
)

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #temp5
    EXEC sp_ParseArray @category, ';'

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_product INTO @category
END;

CLOSE cursor_product;
DEALLOCATE cursor_product;
```

Comment: An alternative to `#temp`, consider use [table variables](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-user-defined-functions/sql-server-table-variables/).

Comment: You haven't defined `sp_ParseArray`, but I think a cursor is not a great way to do this.  My general advice: avoid cursors whenever possible.  Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows) which is similar but splits comma separated values.

Comment: More on why cursors are often considered "bad", and some alternatives: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58141/why-is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-use-cursors-in-sql-server

Comment: And with that out of the way, now for a comment on your actual code: notice that your first `FETCH NEXT` statement happens after you first execute the `sp_ParseArray` method, ie. the first time this executes, `@category` will be null.  This may be affecting your output

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.