# store list of data into variable store procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

First of all i excuse me if this question looks very simple for you. Since, i have no idea how to write sp i am posting this question:

Basically i want to write store procedure for and my use case is:

1. select distinct id from table

   **select id from [table_name]**
2. Iterate for all id fetched
3. Do a query again on another table with this id as parameter
4. Fetch data

Can anyone please suggest how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question I assume there are no input parameters required for the `Stored Procedure`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YourProcedureName --change it to your SP name
AS
BEGIN
    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    --Choose any approach that suits your case better from bellow and remove the rest approach once you finalize it

    /*1st Approach*/
    SELECT * FROM TABLEB 
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TABLEA)

    /*2nd Approach*/
    SELECT * FROM TABLEB B
    JOIN TABLEA A
      ON B.Id = A.Id

    /*3rd Approach which you are expeting*/
    --Implementing CURSOR
    
    DECLARE @Id INT
    DECLARE Table_Cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT 
    DISTINCT Id FROM TABLEA

    OPEN Table_Cursor  
    FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor INTO @Id 

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN  
         -- you can insert it into a table if you need
         SELECT * FROM TABLEB WHERE Id = @Id

         FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor INTO @Id
    END 

    CLOSE Table_Cursor  
    DEALLOCATE Table_Cursor

END
GO
```

Comment: Yes it will. This is for MSSQL, I developed it in SSMS. Just modify the table names and decide the approach you would like to use and comment out or remove other section before creating the SP.

Comment: Why even suggest a cursor, there is almost no scenario when it is useful

Comment: I was suggesting multiple approaches. Not enforcing to use cursors. I beleive there is no harm in knowing about cursors to iterate. Please Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58141/why-is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-use-cursors-in-sql-server

Comment: Yeah, I agree there are some performance issue in using cursor, but if you want to iterate on a table's column then you have to use cursors/while loop to do it, no other way you can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DATA FROM [TABLE2]
WHERE TABLE2.TABLE1ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM [TABLE1])

Either use inner query concept or inner joins concept.